# When true positives are rare

Tags: machine-learning

Suppose you're trying to use machine learning for a classification task like, let's say, looking at photographs of animals and distinguishing horses from zebras. This task would seem to be within the state of the art.

But if you take a bunch of labelled photographs and throw them at something like a neural network or support vector machine, what happens in practice is that zebras are so much rarer than horses that the system just ends up learning to say 'always a horse' because this is actually the way to minimize its error.

Minimal error that may be but it's also not a very useful result. What is the recommended way to tell the system 'I want the best guess at which photographs are zebras, even if this does create some false positives'? There doesn't seem to be a lot of discussion of this problem.

Comment: Just off the top of my head, could you train a model on a data set with an artificially high percentage of zebras, and then use that to find zebras in the actual photographs where they are rare?

Comment: Also, I wish to mention that you could probably get a better response (or find a similar question) on Stack Overflow's sister site "Cross Validated". https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the things I usually do with imbalanced classes (or skewed data sets) is simply generate more data. I think this is the best approach. You could go out in the real world and gather more data of the imbalanced class (e.g. find more pictures of zebras). You could also generate more data by simply making copies or duplicating it with transformations (e.g. flip horizontally).

You could also pick a classifier that uses an alternate evaluation (performance) metric over the one usually used - accuracy. Look at precision/recall/F1 score.

Week 6 of Andrew Ng's ML course talks about this topic: [link](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/lecture/tKMWX/error-metrics-for-skewed-classes)

Here is another good web page I found on handling imbalanced classes: [link](https://machinelearningmastery.com/tactics-to-combat-imbalanced-classes-in-your-machine-learning-dataset/)

Answer (score 1):

With this type of unbalanced data problem, it is a good approach to learn patterns associated with each class as opposed to simply comparing classes - this can be done via unsupervised learning learning first (such as with autoencoders).  A good article with this available at https://www.r-bloggers.com/autoencoders-and-anomaly-detection-with-machine-learning-in-fraud-analytics/amp/.  Another suggestion - after running the classifier, the confusion matrix can be used to determine where additional data should be pursued (I.e. many zebra errors)